# Сделать цикл по QLineEdit и получить данные в список

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Подскажите как можно выхватить данные строк, которые находятся внутри класса. 
Имеется много полей `QLineEdit` и нужно получить из них данные в список.

В примере кода нужно циклом (?) пробежаться по объектам `le902`, `le903`, `le904` и в итоге должен получиться список с данными `[16, 17, 18]`.

```
 self.le902 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
 self.le902.setText("16")
 self.le902.setObjectName("le902")
 self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le902, 1, 0, 1, 1)

 self.le903 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
 self.le903.setText("17")
 self.le903.setObjectName("le903")
 self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le903, 3, 0, 1, 1)

 self.le904 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
 self.le904.setText("18")
 self.le904.setObjectName("le904")
 self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le904, 3, 0, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно виджеты найти через метод [findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren)

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.widget)

        self.le902 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le902.setText("16")
        self.le902.setObjectName("le902")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le902, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.le903 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le903.setText("17")
        self.le903.setObjectName("le903")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le903, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.le904 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le904.setText("18")
        self.le904.setObjectName("le904")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le904, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Получить данные в список.')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_list)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

    def get_list(self):
        items = [lineEdit.text() for lineEdit in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)]  # +++
        self.label.setText(str(items))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так понял это чуть измененная версия варианта "ниже" с меньшим добавлением строк. Будем устраивать мозговой штурм дальше)

Comment: @MacKenny не в количестве строк дело. Здесь совсем другой подход.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то через метод findChildren он ищет все QlineEdit'ы, а дальше составляется список из значений..

Comment: @MacKenny я то думал, что данный ответ был выбран как более оригинальный, а оказалось, что в нем меньше строе :)

Comment: Мне теперь стыдно за свою "зелёность" ) Как минимум Ваш вариант менее затратен в реализации... но даже в таком случае тот ужас, что я составил выдает ошибку "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)" , и кажется это переполнение стека)

Comment: @MacKenny, у вас в каком-то методе ошибка. Добавьте везде  try/except для отлова исключений или добавьте обработчик для необработанных исключений: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e224a84e7bbf745de1eaef42dbd9055c2171214c/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L34 (`sys.excepthook` и функция `log_uncaught_exceptions`, обратите внимание, что нужно импортировать `traceback` и для вывода ошибки используется виджет QMessageBox)

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый приме.

Можно по разному, например создать список.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  
        
        self.lineEdit_list = []                                   # +++
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.widget)  
        
        self.le902 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le902.setText("16")
        self.le902.setObjectName("le902")
        self.lineEdit_list.append(self.le902)                     # +++
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le902, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.le903 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le903.setText("17")
        self.le903.setObjectName("le903")
        self.lineEdit_list.append(self.le903)                     # +++
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le903, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.le904 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le904.setText("18")
        self.le904.setObjectName("le904")
        self.lineEdit_list.append(self.le904)                     # +++
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.le904, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Получить данные в список.')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_list)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
    def get_list(self):
        _list = [lineEdit.text() for lineEdit in self.lineEdit_list]             # +++
        self.label.setText(str(_list))
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На основе вашего ответа сделал свой :)